# Categorizing data in Excel using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I am trying to classify each row as x, y, or z based on both a month and day (a certain time of the year). My categories are:

- X = June 1st - October 1st
- Y = November 15th - April 15th
- Z = All others

I realize this may be simple, but I can't seem to get the formula just right. The table I have looks like:

> Day  Month  Year  Test
>   7      5          2012   Z
>   6      5          2013   Z
>   2      11        2011    Z
>   4      6          2013   Z
>   27    5          2013   Z
>   14    3          2013   Z
>   14    5          2014   Z
>   20    10        2013   Z
>   5      12        2013   Z

My current formula for "Test" is:

=IF(AND(AND(B2>=6,A2>=1),AND(B2<=10,A2<=1)),"X",IF(OR(AND(B2<=4,A2<=15),AND(B2>=11,A2>=15)),"Y","Z"))

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your formula isn't working is that you are testing for both month and day at the same time - for example,

```
IF(AND(B2<=4,A2<=15)
```

will return false for March 16, even though you want it to be true.  This is because your formula doesn't understand the concept of "days and months".

The formula I would use is

```
=IF(AND(DATE(C2,B2,A2)>=DATE(C2,6,1),DATE(C2,B2,A2)<DATE(C2,10,1)), "X",
    IF(OR(DATE(C2,B2,A2)>=DATE(C2,11,15),DATE(C2,B2,A2)<DATE(C2,4,15)), "Y", "Z"))
```

Note - I added an carriage return that shouldn't really be there to make it more readable.

Note also that my formula computes `DATE(C2,B2,A2)` a number of times, and it might be good to have that as a separate (hidden) column. The nice thing about this expression is that it uses the built in `DATE` function which understands about months and days - and it's relatively easy to fix it depending on what the date range criteria are. With your test dates, it gives the following:

```
Day  Month  Year   Test
 7     5    2012     Z
 6     5    2013     Z
 2    11    2011     Z
 4     6    2013     X
27     5    2013     Z
14     3    2013     Y
14     5    2014     Z
20    10    2013     Z
 5    12    2013     Y
```

Note - updated after @pnuts pointed out error...

Also note... there are a total of 4 conditions in the above - and I took some liberty in deciding what dates to include. Basically, I translated your requirements as follows:

```
date >= Nov 15 of this year          ==> "Y"
date < April 15 of this year         ==> "Y"
date >= June 1 AND date < Oct 1      ==> "X"
else "Z"
```

This may not be *exactly* what you wanted but it should be obvious how the expressions work, and you should be able to adjust as needed (in particular it was not clear if the 15th of April should be part of "Y" or "Z", for example.)

I think it would be useful to define a series of variables (maybe on a hidden sheet)

```
startXmonth = 4
startXday = 15
stopXmonth = 10
stopXday = 1
```

etc, and then you can use these names instead of "magic numbers" in your formula. That way, if you decide you want to change the range of dates corresponding to a particular tariff, you can change it in a sensible place, rather than somewhere buried in a formula. You may think it is extra work now, but you will thank me later...

Finally, you might want to make all the dates "Up to and including" - using `<=` and `>=`, and defining the first and last day (rather than, as above, the first day to include and the first day not to include).

Let me know if this all makes sense.

Comment: Thank you Floris!! This worked great! I took your advice of adding a date column and variables for the X/Y/Z thresholds as well as the more clear definition of the first and last days/using <= and >= for clarity. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Untested (expected results would have helped) please try:

```
=IF(OR(AND(B2<5,A2<16),AND(B2=11,A2>14),B2=12),"Y",IF(OR(AND(B2>5,B2<10),AND(B2=10,A2=1)),"X","Z"))
```